# I am getting an unexpected result while I use matches function in Scala. Can any body tell me why?

Tags: regex, scala

As i am comparing the two variable with same value assigned , the result is false , may be its because of * character. I need the result for further processing of my program and it must be true. Please tell me the solution.

> scala> var c="PASSWD\\*\\*\\*\\*\\*\\*\\*\\*"
>
> c: java.lang.String = PASSWD\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*
>
> scala> var d="PASSWD\\*\\*\\*\\*\\*\\*\\*\\*"
>
> d: java.lang.String = PASSWD\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*
>
> scala> println(c.matches(d))
>
> false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is coming from the fact that you need to escape *s in your regex, but not in your string so I think what you actually mean is..

```
val c = "PASSWD********"
val d = "PASSWD\\*\\*\\*\\*\\*\\*\\*\\*"
```

then

```
scala> println(c.matches(d))
true
```

Comment: Thanks , my problem is solved